# Record audio and play it afterwards

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-sdcard

I wrote a class that shall make it possible to record an audio, save it to the sd card and then play the result. Here is my code:

```
 public void recordAudio(final String fileName) {
        final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.reset();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, fileName);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        final String myPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyOwnQuiz/" + fileName + ".3gp";
        recorder.setOutputFile(myPath);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Record audio");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setButton (DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Stop recording", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();

                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

                File f = new File(myPath);
                if(f.exists()){
                    try{
                        mp.setDataSource(myPath);
                        mp.prepare();
                    }catch(IOException e){

                    }
                    mp.start();
                }

            }
        });

        mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface p1) {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            }
        });
        recorder.start();
        mProgressDialog.show();


    }
```

The recording works fine. The recorded file also appears on my sd card, just as I want it to be. But can't get the app to play this recorded audio. As you can see I tried it just in the BUTTON_POSITIV. After pressing the stop button the audio shall be saved and the audio played once. What am I doing wrong?

This is how I am calling the function:

```
Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            String myString = myCal.getTime().toString();
                            recordAudio(myString);
```

Comment: Does  if(f.exists()) return true?

Comment: Checked it again: Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the recorded file's descriptor to the setDataSource() method instead :

```
 File f = new File(myPath);
                if(f.exists()){
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
 FileDescriptor fileD = fis.getFD();
                 try{
                        mp.setDataSource(fileD);
                        mp.prepare();
                    }catch(IOException e){

                    }
                    mp.start();
}
```