# Record/stream audio and play it back while talking | Website

Tags: javascript, audio, stream, web

I am unable to write anything to allow this, but I was hoping for someone to point me in the right direction on finding a code that would do that. I am good with HTML & CSS, and very novice to JS.

What I need is to be able to use my microphone to speak in a single page website and it would stream it back. That way I can have a chromecast casting my voice to the TV while displaying the website's content.

I hope someone could help me out! I found this JS snippet here: [Record audio and play it afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971334/record-audio-and-play-it-afterwards)

but I need to be able to "stream" it right as I speak.

Cheers!

Comment: So are you wanting to actually "stream" the microphone or just have it playback?

Comment: Thank you for asking @NewToJS . I am not  100% sure what the term would be. But what I am trying to do is have an HTML webpage on my computer that I can open and it will allow me to speak to a microphone and play it back right as I speak. So that I can cast the tab to a TV and hear myself talk.

Answer (score 0):

Using web audio API can help you here. [MDN has an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamTrackSource) on their webpage regarding sending audio input to audio output. Here is their sample code:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio: true, video: false})
.then(function(stream) {
  let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  let source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // Handle getUserMedia() error
});
```

You will need to attach that function to a user input event, such as clicking a button.